# Reduce the number of rows in a random matrix created with randn

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
x = [randn(30,1); 5+randn(30,1)];
```

It has 60 rows. How could I reduce the number of rows without disturbing the density?

Comment: its means that in the same range and same value.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. if you want to reduce the number of rows, just use a number smaller than 30...

Comment: So, for the example given, you'd like to *remove* 2 rows, 1 from the top part and 1 from the bottom part? Do you always have knowledge of where the parts start/end? Should the removal be random, or just remove the first entry or so? Can you please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Mahyar, did my answer prove useful, or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use reshape function to change the dimensions of your matrix without changing the contents:

```
x=reshape(x,m,n)
```

yields an m x n matrix. The number of entries must not change, so m*n must be equal 60 in your case.

Comment: i need function like imresize

Comment: @Mahyar do you mean you simply need to drop some rows? you can do x = x(1:2:end) to drop every second row.